# Best And Cheapest Way To Isolate Multiple DC Power Sources

Tags: power-supply, power, dc, isolation

I need a way to create/simulate (by simulate I mean fool the circuit in to thinking they're isolated), at least 8 5v 1A power sources in the cheapest and easiest way possible.

I have a power source which is 5-5.5v and at least 8A (10A actually), but I need to split that source out to 8 other devices but that are completely isolated from the original source. If it's not isolated the units I'm supplying power to will short.

I've tried a schotkey rectifier but that does't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Example below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqqovT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 8x DC-DC converters will provide pretty good isolation (up to a few kV depending on the model). But maybe you mean something else by "isolation". It would still be possible for the outputs to interact if they were (for example) shorted and they overloaded the source.

Comment: Go on eBay and buy 10 AC/DC 5 volt 1 amp isolated power supplies. That way you'll have 2 spares. Should cost about 30 bucks. Well, that's cheapest. 1 out of 2 ain't bad in baseball.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast ;) If you are allowed to simulate them (the OP does say "create/simulate"), that's got to be cheaper than ebay!

Comment: Yeah, simulation has got to be cheaper than buying but, what could "best" mean?

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany I'm aware of DC-DC isolating converters, I was hoping for a more simple and perhaps more 'DIY' approach possibly using components I already have rather than have to buy something.

Sorry about the 'simulation' I typed this at night when I was really tired! :/

Comment: @Andyaka - Well, by one standard you could argue that simulation is best. After all, you don't actually expect a simulation to work reliably.